# Postfix - centOS 7

Tags: email, centos, postfix-mta

I'm currently trying to install and make Postfix, dovecot works.
I've followed this tutorial [right here](https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mariadb-on-centos-7/)
But right now, I'm facing a "permission denied" error:
tail /var/log/maillog shows me:

```
warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf is unavailable. open /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf: Permission denied
```

The permissions for all these mysql-*.cf files are:

```
ls -ld /etc/postfix/mysql*.cf:
-rw-r-----. 1 root postfix 151 Apr 17 18:07 /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
-rw-r-----. 1 root postfix 142 Apr 17 18:08 /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-email2email.cf
-rw-r-----. 1 root postfix 139 Apr 17 18:05 /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
-rw-r-----. 1 root postfix 138 Apr 17 18:06 /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
```

What permission should these files have? 
I don't understand why it denies it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `postfix set-permissions`?

Comment: Wow! That seemed to work! Thank you a lot!